# I am getting error while executing aws cloudformation template,throwing error ROLLBACK_COMPLETE

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: "Template to set up Kinesis stream, Lambda functions, S3 bucket, DynamoDB table and related IAM roles for AWS Lambda Real-time Stream Processing Reference Architecture. PLEASE NOTE: The CloudFormation Stack Name must be all lowercase as it is used as part of the S3 bucket name. Otherwise the stack creation will fail."
Parameters: 
  LambdaS3Bucket: 
    Type: String
    Default: awslambda-reference-architectures
    Description: Name of S3 bucket where Lambda function packages are stored.
  LambdaDDBEventProcessorS3Key:
    Type : String
    Default : stream-processing/ddb_eventprocessor.zip
    Description : Name of S3 key for Zip with Stream Processing DynamoDB Event Processor Lambda function package.
  LambdaDDBEventProcessorHandler:
    Type : String
    Default : ddb_eventprocessor.handler
    Description : Name of handler for Stream Processing DynamoDB Event Processor Lambda function.
Resources:
  EventStream:
    Type: 'AWS::Kinesis::Stream'
    Properties:
      ShardCount: 1
  DDBEventProcessor:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Description: Stream Processing DDB Event Processor
      Handler: !Ref LambdaDDBEventProcessorHandler
      MemorySize: 128
      Role: !GetAtt 
        - EventProcessorExecutionRole
        - Arn
      Timeout: 10
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: !Ref LambdaS3Bucket
        Key: !Ref LambdaDDBEventProcessorS3Key
      Events:
        Stream:
          Type: Kinesis
          Properties:
            Stream: !GetAtt EventStream.Arn
            StartingPosition: TRIM_HORIZON
            BatchSize: 25
  EventDataTable:
    Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: Username
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: Id
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: Username
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: Id
          KeyType: RANGE
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: '1'
        WriteCapacityUnits: '1'
      TableName: !Join 
        - ''
        - - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
          - '-EventData'
  EventProcessorExecutionRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: EventProcessorExecutionPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:*'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'dynamodb:BatchWriteItem'
                Resource: !Join 
                  - ''
                  - - 'arn:aws:dynamodb:'
                    - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                    - ':'
                    - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                    - ':table/'
                    - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
                    - '-EventData'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaKinesisExecutionRole'
  streamprocessingclient:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::User'
  ClientPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    Properties:
      PolicyName: StreamProcessingClientPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'kinesis:Put*'
            Resource: !Join 
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:kinesis:'
                - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                - ':'
                - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                - ':stream/'
                - !Ref EventStream
      Users:
        - !Ref streamprocessingclient
  ClientKeys:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::AccessKey'
    Properties:
      UserName: !Ref streamprocessingclient
Outputs:
  AccessKeyId:
    Value: !Ref ClientKeys
    Description: AWS Access Key Id of stream processing client user
  SecretAccessKey:
    Value: !GetAtt 
      - ClientKeys
      - SecretAccessKey
    Description: AWS Secret Key of stream processing client user
  KinesisStream:
    Value: !Ref EventStream
    Description: The Kinesis stream used for ingestion.
  Region:
    Value: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
    Description: The region this template was launched in.
```

Hi ,this is my cloudformation template ,which should 
creates a Kinesis Stream

Creates a DynamoDB table named -EventData

Creates Lambda Function 1 (-DDBEventProcessor) which receives records from Kinesis and writes records to the DynamoDB table

Creates an IAM Role and Policy to allow the event processing Lambda function read from the Kinesis Stream and write to the DynamoDB table

Creates an IAM user with permission to put events in the Kinesis stream together with credentials for the user to use in an API client

but I am getting error ,ROllBACK_COMPLETE ,please suggest me if any changes need.Thanks in advance .

Comment: Your stack creation failed. Take a look at the events, it will tell you what failed and (hopefully) why.

Comment: Please add the `Events` output here so we can see what actually caused it. It can be found on AWS CloudFormation console by selecting this stack.

Comment: Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey. S3 Error Message: The specified key does not exist. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 4e5fcaff-df10-402c-a6c6-b1c69d1c19a7)  .My bucket name is stream-processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) warns:

```
E2531: Deprecated runtime (nodejs6.10) specified. Updating disabled since 2019-06-30, please consider to update to nodejs10.x
```

Comment: Hi I am getting same error after changing to nodejs10.x also

Comment: Can you find the first `CREATE_FAILED` / `UPDATE_FAILED` event in the `Events` tab?

Comment: Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey. S3 Error Message: The specified key does not exist. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 4e5fcaff-df10-402c-a6c6-b1c69d1c19a7)